# how to write to a dbf file in asp.net?

Tags: c#, dbf

I want to create a .dbf file. Can anyone help me out how to do that using c#.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to insert record to dbf file via asp net - vbCity - The .NET ...

http://vbcity.com/forums/t/74564.aspx